Why can't a third acetyl-CoA condense with acetoacetyl-CoA in the same way, as two acetyl-CoAs condense in the thiolase reaction?
In the biochemical ketogenesis pathway, acetoacetyl-CoA reacts with  acetyl-CoA to form HMG-CoA (3-hydroxy-3-methylglutaryl-CoA), in a reaction catalysed by HMG-CoA synthase.
But why can't acetoacetyl-CoA simply condense with another acetyl-CoA, just like two acetyl-CoAs condensed to form acetoacetyl-CoA in the thiolase reaction?

Welcome to SE Biology. It is unclear to me what you mean by your question,  so I have edited it to make clear what I think it is likely to mean. I assume you are concerned with ketogenesis and are wondering why a separate enzyme is needed rather than thiolase. If this is NOT  what you meant, please explain and ammend the question. The answer, is likely to be obvious. Are the two reactions chemically the same? If not, will the same enzyme be able to catalyse them?

If you wish an informed answer to your question, please confirm or rebut my interpretation of your intent.
